# jaxb not converting inner wrapper dto

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jaxb2

Below is my class structure:

```
       class ResponseWsDTO {
           Map<Date, List<ComplexTypeWsDTO>> mapFieldName;
       String field1;
       String field2;

       }
       class ComplexTypeWsDTO {
           String complexField1;
           String complexField2;
           String complexField3;
       }
```

Below is the response I am getting right now,

```
  {
      "field1": 6,
      "field2": 28,
      "mapFieldName": [
          {
              "key": "2018-01-16T00:00:00+04:00",
              "value": [
                  "com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@ca8c540",
                  "com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@79888653",
                  "com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@77d56457",
                  "com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@10985dac",
                  "com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@5a50083a",
                  "com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@6757b73d"
              ]
          },
          {
              "key": "2018-01-17T00:00:00+04:00",
              "value": [
                  "com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@3bfc905c",
                  "com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@69dbdfb2",
                  "com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@33901b6b",
                  "com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@69a4ac7b",
                  "com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@3605bf63",
                  "com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@194d05e"
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
```

We don't want to have `com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@194d05e` in response, it should be replaced with its fields. means properties of the pojo ComplexTypeWsDTO should be there in the response.

expected response is below

```
{
    "field1": 6,
    "field2": 28,
    "mapFieldName": [
        {
            "key": "2018-01-21T00:00:00+04:00",
            "value": {
                "complexType": [
                    {
                        "beginTime": "09",
                        "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
                        "deliveryDate": "21 January",
                        "deliverySlotCode": "8796094245625",
                        "endTime": "11 am",
                        "expired": true,
                        "isAvailable": true,
                        "pos": "003",
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "beginTime": "11",
                        "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
                        "deliveryDate": "21 January",
                        "deliverySlotCode": "8796094278393",
                        "endTime": "01 pm",
                        "expired": true,
                        "isAvailable": true,
                        "pos": "003",
                        "selected": false
                    }
                    ]
                    }
        }]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code product this?

Comment: Not sure what are you asking ? can you post expected output ?

Comment: @ravi I am expecting Properties of pojo in response instead of 
"com.sample.commercewebservices.dto.ComplexTypeWsDTO@3bfc905c"
I have updated expected response please have a look.

Comment: @PushpakJain basically, you need to object value instead of object reference. This is totally depending on your implementation. You need to share your server side implementation